# Zooming - Plus/Minus Buttons or Slider

Tags: zooming

I can't but think like a programmer here, although I'm aware that this can turn out as a silly question.

Would a user prefer a slider or buttons for zooming in/out?

No default zooming factor

There is a min and a max zooming factor

Zoom steps are block-incremeneted; slider's moving piece would snap to zoom values

Comment: ...Why not both?

Comment: @lunchmeat317 Overkill.

Comment: You sure? Generally, map sliders have a plus (zoom) and a minus (zoom out) button at the top and bottom, respectively. Check out [Mapquest](http://www.mapquest.com/) - I wouldn't call that "overkill".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slider has many advantages over two buttons:

- single widget for single purpose (zooming)
- graphically shows the relative zoom factor
- indicates how much more zooming in/out is possible (the buttons' enabled state would only indicate when the min/max zoom level is reached)
- selection of the preferred zoom level by dragging (compared to clicking multiple times on the buttons, which gets even worse the more intermediate zoom values are introduced)

Comment: Valid arguments. Good enough for me.

Answer (score 4):

I know this may be a big ask, but pretty much every user has become so familiar with the functionalities available on Google Maps that they expect most zooming interfaces, especially maps, should behave in the following ways.

- Double Click to zoom in
- Use mouse wheel to zoom in or out
- Additional zoom slider control
- On a touch screen, two fingers pinch and expand control

Comment: That should be "double-click to zoom in", right?

Comment: It depends on what you're zooming in on, but I agree that it's generally best to support multiple forms of zooming, especially with the double-click zooming (which is consistent with double-tap zooming on mobile, and allows zooming in on a specific point, instead of the centre). Worth noting that you mean "multitouch" screen, though; not every touch screen supports multiple touch points.

Comment: @couchand Yes. I meant double click. Thanks! I fixed it.